# Magento 2: Can we run a magento root file from CRON?

Tags: magento2, cron

I want to run a file which i placed in root directory of my magento. How to run that file using CRON ?

**UPDATE:**

I have a file name updateData.php in magento root directory. How to run this file from cron?

```
    <group id="default">
        <job name="daily_csv_file_generate" instance="Namespace\Module\Cron\Test" method="testFile">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
```

Comment: "How to run that file using CRON", you want run this files  with magento cron?

Comment: You can explain more details?

Comment: I have a file in magento root dir. and i want to run that file from CRON. How ?

Comment: You want to read this file or execute any function?

Comment: I updated my question. I want to execute function of that file. How to setup in crontab.xml file to run updateData.php file ?

Comment: I think you should under `pub` folder.

Comment: then how to set instance="Namespace\Module\Cron\Test" method="testFile" for pub also ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52064/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-borncoder).